# как правильно написать программу, которая будет работать столько раз сколько тебе надо?

Tags: python

Пишу программу в которой пользователь будет вводить слова, а программа будет выдавать их наоборот. После 3 слов программа будет задавать вопрос пользователю о завершения игры. Если игрок согласился продолжить игру, то он может ввести еще 3 слова и так пока пользователь не захочет завершить игру.
Как и какой цикл здесь нужно использовать для повторения функции?

```
 print("Привет! Это игра Слова наоборот.")
 name = input("Как тебя зовут? ")
 quest = input("Привет, "+ name + "!" + " Загадывай слово ")
 quest1 = quest[::-1]
 print(quest1)

 def first_game(word):
 word = input("Загадай слово ")
 word1 = word[::-1]
 print(word1)

 word2 = input("Закончить игру?")
 if word2 == "нет":
     first_game(word2)
 else:
     print("Пока.")
```

Comment: да просто сделайте вечный цикл и прерывайтесь на введенное пустое слово. Или именно 3 слова надо?

Answer (score 1):

а что у вас не так то? просто в функцию `first_game` добавьте цикл

```
def first_game(word):
    for i in range(3):
        word = input("Загадай слово ")
        word1 = word[::-1]
        print(word1)
```

или вам что-то иное нужно?

Comment: Именно это и нужно было. Спасибо.